# Laravel(5.3.24+) Validation: Validate 2 columns

Tags: validation, laravel-5.3

Using the new style of laravel validation seen here: https://laravel-news.com/unique-and-exists-validation

I would like the name column to be required & only unique for a competition.

Using the example table below, 
id 3: The validation should stop this from happening, because "a name already exist for that competition".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom rule

The best solution would be to create a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules) for this, that accepts the field with the corresponding competition_id as a parameter.

Something like

```
//Calling the custom rule like this
['name' => 'required|validateName:yourCompetitionIdFormFieldHere'];
```

Declaring the custom validation function in your service provider like this

```
Validator::extend('validateName', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   $competitionId = ($validator->data, $parameters[0]);

   //Now check if the $value is already set for the specific competition_id by using normal database queries and comparison
  return count(Team::where("comeptition_id", "=", $competitionId)->whereName($value)->get()) == 0
});
```

---

### What does it

The custom validation rule receives the data of the field you give with the function (in the code above it's `yourCompetitionIdFormFieldHere`), so it knows which league/competition_id the user chose. With this information, you now can check if there is already a similar ame for the entered id.